# running maven-jetty-plugin fails during deployment

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, openshift, maven-jetty-plugin

i've been searching all over for an answer. every time I push my code to Openshift, the build fails in the same place. It's a Tomcat 6 application.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty- plugin:6.1.26:run (start-jetty) on project ontopia-webed: Failure: Permission denied -> [Help 1]
```

intially jetty was starting up at 0.0.0.0 and getting a permission denied warning before the failure, so I found out my OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP address and added it to pom.xml for jetty to use. that solved the permission denied warning when it starts, but it still fails just the same. any help greatly appreciated!

```
remote: [INFO] <<< maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (start-jetty) @ ontopia-webed <<<
remote: [INFO] 
remote: [INFO] --- maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (start-jetty) @ ontopia-webed ---
remote: [INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: Ontopia Webed
remote: [INFO] Webapp source directory = /var/lib/openshift/564d4d902d527141810000f6/app-root/runtime/repo/ontopia-webed/target/test-webapp
remote: [INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
remote: [INFO] Classes = /var/lib/openshift/564d4d902d527141810000f6/app-root/runtime/repo/ontopia-webed/target/classes
remote: 2015-11-19 03:24:47.837:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
remote: [INFO] Context path = /webedtest
remote: [INFO] Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
remote: [INFO] Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
remote: [INFO] Web overrides =  none
remote: [INFO] web.xml file = /var/lib/openshift/564d4d902d527141810000f6/app-root/runtime/repo/ontopia-webed/target/test-webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
remote: [INFO] Webapp directory = /var/lib/openshift/564d4d902d527141810000f6/app-root/runtime/repo/ontopia-webed/target/test-webapp
remote: [INFO] Starting jetty 6.1.26 ...
remote: 2015-11-19 03:24:47.987:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
remote: 2015-11-19 03:24:48.144:INFO::No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
remote: 2015-11-19 03:24:49.319:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@127.5.100.1:9090
remote: [INFO] Started Jetty Server
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Reactor Summary:
remote: [INFO] 
remote: [INFO] Ontopia ........................................... SUCCESS [5.127s]
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Engine .................................... SUCCESS [1:04.256s]
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Navigator ................................. SUCCESS [17.939s]
remote: [INFO] Ontopia OSL Schema ................................ SUCCESS [7.077s]
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Content Store ............................. SUCCESS [4.559s]
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Webed ..................................... FAILURE [17.060s]
remote: [INFO] Ontopia DB2TM ..................................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia TMRAP ..................................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia TMRAP Axis Archive ........................ SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Vizigator ................................. SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Classify .................................. SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Realm ..................................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia RDF ....................................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopoly Editor ................................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia TopicMapPreferences ....................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia JDBC Spy 7 ................................ SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia ROOT webapplication ....................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Access Control webapplication ............. SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia 'Scripts and languages' webapplication .... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia XML tools webapplication .................. SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Manager webapplication .................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Omnigator webapplication .................. SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Ontopoly webapplication ................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Ontopoly webapplication (standalone) ...... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia TMRAP webapplication ...................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] Ontopia Distribution Tomcat 6 ..................... SKIPPED
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 2:01.082s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 19 03:24:49 EST 2015
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 25M/116M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (start-jetty) on project ontopia-webed: Failure: Permission denied -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: "Permission denied" is pretty clear. Which OS are you using? Does the current user have the correct permission to write at the target folder?

Comment: You can try tailing OpenShift logs by `rhc tail <yourAppName>` (and then push your code again) to get more info about why it is failing.

Comment: hey thanks guys! i tried your suggestion of tailing the logs, but there wasn't any new info in there. i'm backing off figuring out this deployment for now to focus on more pressing issues.